# How to put a limit to the zoom?

Tags: javascript, css

I want to limit the zoom for my div, but i don't know how to do it.

At first i tried to limit the action of zooming when the variable zoom were (zoom < 1 || zoom > 3) to not zoom a lot. But i ended up making the program just stop.

```js
const zoomElement = document.querySelector(".workspace");
let zoom = 1;
const ZOOM_SPEED = 0.5;

document.addEventListener("wheel", function(e) {
  if (e.deltaY > 0) {
    zoomElement.style.transform = `scale(${(zoom -= ZOOM_SPEED)})`;
  } else {
    zoomElement.style.transform = `scale(${(zoom += ZOOM_SPEED)})`;
  }
});
```

```css
.workspace {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100vh;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="workspace">
  <h1>Zoom</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Answer is literally in the documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/wheel_event

Answer (score 1):

You can restrict zoom value from reaching min and max value, e.g.

```
zoom = Math.min(Math.max(0.125, zoom), 4);
```

above code will prevent zoom value from dropping below `0.125` and being higher than `4`. This example is literally from [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/wheel_event).

Working code:

```js
const zoomElement = document.querySelector(".workspace");
let zoom = 1;
const ZOOM_SPEED = 0.01;

document.addEventListener("wheel", function(evt) {
  zoom += evt.deltaY * -ZOOM_SPEED;
  zoom = Math.min(Math.max(1, zoom), 3);
  zoomElement.style.transform = `scale(${zoom})`;
});
```

```css
.workspace {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100vh;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="workspace">
  <h1>Zoom</h1>
</div>
```